# rbindlist - how to get an additional column with info about a source?

Tags: r, fread, rbindlist

I have more than 30 large .csv files stored in one folder. I would like to read them in R as one data.frame/data/table with the following criteria:

(1) first and last 25 rows of each file should be skipped (number of rows differs in each file)

(2) last column should contain unique information on the source of the row (eg. filename.csv.rownumber from the raw file). A number of columns differ in each file as well.

So far I have this:

```
ASC_files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

read_ASC <- function(x){
ASC <-fread(x, skip=25)
return(ASC[1:(nrow(ASC)-25),])
}

ASC_list <-lapply(ASC_files, read_ASC)
ASC_all <- rbindlist(ASC_list, use.names=TRUE)
```

However, I have no idea how to get an additional column with information on the source of each row...

Comment: You can use the `idcol` argument

Comment: I've tried idcol=TRUE but as a result I'm receiving a column with numbers from 1 to nrow(ASC_all), not the information on filename and number of row from the source file

Comment: `idcol` will put the index, or the name of the list element if there is one. If you want `idcol` to have the filenames, you can put `ASC_files <- setNames(ASC_files , ASC_files )` after the first line, thereby naming your list and feeding the right thing to `idcol`

Comment: Thanks for the tip it works very well with the name of the file! But I do need also the information about the number of row from the raw file - this and the name of a file is later a key for merging the dataframe with another one. And since I'm skipping first and last 25 rows and files have a different number of rows it's not so easy (at least for me)...

Comment: Can you just add the row number to each frame before trying to rbind them together? `ASC$rn <- seq_len(nrow(ASC))`; return(ASC[...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for commenting my question. Finally, I came out with this solution:

```
ASC_files <- list.files(pattern="*.asc")
ASC_all <- sapply(ASC_files, function(x) read.csv(x, header=FALSE, col.names
paste0('V', 1:1268) , sep="", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#adding a new column with name of the source file
ASC_all <- mapply(cbind, ASC_all, "source"=ASC_files, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#adding a new column with row number
ASC_all <- map(ASC_all, ~rowid_to_column(.x, var="row"))
#removing last and first 25 rows in each dataframe of the list
ASC_all <- lapply(ASC_all, function(x) x[x$row<(nrow(x)-25),])
ASC_all <- lapply(ASC_all, function(x) x[x$row>25,])
#transforming the list into a dataframe with all data
ASC_all <- rbindlist(ASC_all)
#complementing the kolumn source with the row number (result: filename.csv.rownumber)
ASC_all$file <- paste0(ASC_all$file, '.', ASC_all$row)
#removing column with row numbers
ASC_all$row <- NULL
```

Maybe it's not the most elegant and efficient code but at least it works.